# Why is this java applet failing?

Tags: java, applet, cross-browser

I know very little about Java but I'm attempting to run this applet from here:
http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/ only run it locally. So i just changed the page source to this:

```
<applet archive="dist/javaproj-1.0.6.jar" code="Proj.class" width="690" height="600">
</p>
```

But then i get this error from any browser:

```
ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Proj cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Any ideas what i am missing here?
thanks.

Comment: Missing a lot of code in the post.

Comment: There's a lot of code and it's all posted here:http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmapprojlib/files/latest/download. I was not certain which code to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `Proj` class extends the `Applet` class.

Comment: does not appear to be so but then i'm wondering how it works on that site. And if the source code differs from the web site's applet, how can i test the source code. Sorry for my lack of java knowledge.

Comment: It might be used other than as an Applet. An Applet is a particular way of executing files in a browser. Maybe they are doing something else like using Java Web Start. If the code is intended to be an Applet, it has to extend the Applet class.

Comment: @FrancisUpton is there any other way without extending the Applet class? as JFrame ( that not required to extends the JFrame class)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an applet and not a full application?